# Output of filter is a pulse sequence

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, simulation, output

Like I have been advised in this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/595411/how-to-verify-the-voltage-and-frequency-response-in-a-simulated-equalizer/595507#595507), I revised and updated the circuit to a more workable model,
[image]

but at the end Im getting this output(the blue is the input and the red is the amplified and filtered (!?) signal):
[image]
But I was expecting something like the yellow signal taken before the last amplifier versus the input
[image]
Can someone explain me how to interpret this outputs, because I don't know if its right or wrong or the meaning of the signals, I expected something like a pulse (not a pulse) in some stages like the low pass, but not here.
Thanks for your kind support.

Comment: What happens to the waveform if you increase Rout? Not really my field, but I think your load impedance is too low for an opamp that's specced for 10mA output current.

Comment: Rout= 5 Ohm is very low ? Value can be as 2k Ohm or more for TL084 ...

Comment: @hobbs and Antonio51, I choosed to use a Rout=8 Ohms, since ideally the output must be a speaker, and usually these comes in these value, but I will check these component.

Comment: Ok for the 8 Ohms ... but then choose a power amplifier which is able to drive the speaker.